Docker Compose Watch populates <none> images
I'm writing an application using ASP.NET Core 8 and SQL Server.
I use docker-compose watch feature to rebuild my image every time there's a source code change
Here's my Dockerfile for .NET app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY Test.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=5001
EXPOSE 5001
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Test.dll" ]

and here is my docker-compose file that ups 2 services (.NET app and database)
services:
  api:
    container_name: test-api
    build:
      context: ./Test
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./Test
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      db: 
        condition: service_healthy
  
  db:
    container_name: test-mssql-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "pass_1234"
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - mssql:/var/opt/mssql
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P pass_1234 -Q 'SELECT 1' || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 3s 

volumes:
  mssql:
    

The problem is that every time I change my code, it populates  images, each around 200 MB. Thus polluting docker images. Can I somehow make it update the existing image instead?

Aside... SA_PASSWORD has been deprecated for a couple of years now. As per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation you should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead.

This happens every time you rebuild an image with the same name; it's not unique to the new Compose watch: functionality.  docker system prune can clean these up.

Thanks for the answer...
So am I right that there is no automatic clean-up of those images? problem is if every single code base change introduces a new image, that can overflow the memory within half an hour of work..
